# fcolorbox without borders

Tags: color, border

I'm using `\fcolorbox` (from `xcolor`) to get a coloured page. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to hide/remove the border keeping the page coloured. This is the command I'm currently using and even keeping the first parenthesis empty, the border is still black:

```
\fcolorbox{black}{blue!05}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Couldn't you simply have set the border color the same as the  other color? That said,  David's solution is clearly superior.

Comment: You mention "page": there is a `\pagecolor{...}` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\colorbox`  which is the same but doesn't add a border (and just takes one color argument)  so

```
\colorbox{blue!05}{...}
```